# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint *table*. Cannot insert duplicate key in object *object*

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_GroupMessageUser'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.GroupMessageUser'. The duplicate key value is (a67d44a8-9cd3-4768-5387-08da53ba34db, d8d47ef6-9616-41d5-be94-19b836a1dff9).

I have a problem while updating. I updated first(added GroupMessage) next i tried to update again for any reason and i get this exception.

There is classes :

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string StreetLine1 { get; set; }
    public string StreetLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    // NAVIGATION PROPERTIES
    public virtual IList<GroupMessage> GroupMessage { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Advertisement> Advertisements { get; set; }
    public virtual Validation Validation { get; set; }
}

public class GroupMessage
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // NAVIGATION PROPERTIES
    public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

There is update method :

```
public static EntityEntry<TEntity> UpdateSafe<TEntity>(this DbContext context, TEntity entity)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var currentEntity = context.FindLocalEntry(entity);

        if (currentEntity != null)
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(currentEntity.Entity, entity))
            {
                currentEntity.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currentEntity = context.Update(entity);
        }

        return currentEntity;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You have a violation in the `PRIMARY KEY`. Where is your update command?

Comment: Added update method

Comment: What are you updating? Looking at the message, the error is coming from your join table.